# Linux "traceroute -A" (AS path lookup) equivalent for Win XP?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, bgp, as-number

Can anyone recommend a Win XP command-line **traceroute** implementation providing a function equivalent to the Linux "**traceroute -A**" option, **which includes in its output the BGP AS number** (Autonomous System) for each hop traversed ?

Thanks

Comment: It could be an overkill, but you could install `cygwin`.

Answer (score 1):

About all I can find is something that does it in a [GUI](http://www.netscantools.com/nstpro_traceroute.html), and it's not anything like free. I think ott's suggestion of `cygwin` may be your best bet, especially if you're looking for a command line option.